# How to get nested groups (subgroups) in System.DirectoryServices.Protocol in c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, ldap-query

I have a function which gets parameter as `Distringuished name` of a group and returns the nested groups or groups within a given group using `SearchRequest` query and `SearchResponse`. The code works fine when I use `DirectoryEntry` but failed when I use `LdapConnection` class. It is necessary to work with `LdapConnection` class. Please find below the code snippet:

```
public static void GetNestedGroups(string strGroupDN)
{
    var _currentDomainofLoggedinUser = Domain.GetComputerDomain();

    var currentDomainofLoggedinUser = Domain.GetComputerDomain();
    var currentDomainController = currentDomainofLoggedinUser.FindDomainController(); //Gets the current Domain controller

    var domainName = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
    string strPath = "LDAP://" + currentDomainController.Name; //Gets the current domain controller name
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
    using (LdapConnection ldap = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(domainName, 636)))
    {
        ldap.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
        ldap.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = false;
        var s = new SecureString();
        NetworkCredential network = new NetworkCredential(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, s);

        string ldapSearchFilter = String.Format
              ("(&(memberOf={0})(objectClass=group))", strGroupDN);
        NetworkCredential cred = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        ldap.Bind(network);
        string[] attributesToReturn = new string[] { "distinguishedName" };


        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(strGroupDN, ldapSearchFilter, SearchScope.OneLevel, attributesToReturn);
        searchRequest.DistinguishedName =
            strGroupDN;


        searchRequest.Filter = String.Format
               ("(&(memberOf={0})(objectClass=group))", strGroupDN);
        SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)ldap.SendRequest(searchRequest);
        if (response != null && response.Entries.Count > 0)
        {
            SearchResultEntry obj = response.Entries[0];

            var groupCount = ((System.Collections.CollectionBase)(obj.Attributes["memberOf"])).Count;
            foreach (SearchResultEntry entry in response.Entries)
            {
                var groupName = entry.DistinguishedName;
                _subGroupList.Add(groupName.ToString().Split('=')[1].Split(',')[0]);
                GetNestedGroups(groupName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In the response it doesn't give anything. (In case of `DirectoryEntry`, it does provide the result)

Comment: Be aware, that in AD I can make GroupA member of GroupB and GroupB member of GroupA at the same time. In this you will be having an endless recursion

Comment: And be aware that memberOf attribute does not include groups from other domains (if you have ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any group , we can get a group object using the below query:-

```
public static void GetUsersCorrespondingToGroupChild(string strGroupDN)
{
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.DistinguishedName = strGroupDN;
    searchRequest.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=Group)(CN={0}))", strGroupDN.ToString().Split('=')[1].Split(',')[0]);
    SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)ldap.SendRequest(searchRequest);
    if (response != null && response.Entries.Count > 0)
    {
        SearchResultEntry obj = response.Entries[0];//I get group object here
        if (obj.Attributes["member"] != null)
        {
            var childCount = ((System.Collections.CollectionBase)(obj.Attributes["member"])).Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
            {
                string groupName = obj.Attributes["member"][i].ToString();//I get all members in which i have to find subgroups
                List<string> localGroupList = new List<string>();
                if (groupName.Contains("OU=Groups"))
                {
                    var attributes = obj.Attributes.AttributeNames;
                    string attributesstr = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var item in attributes)
                    {
                        attributesstr = attributesstr + "," + item;
                    }
                    _subGroupList.Add(groupName.ToString().Split('=')[1].Split(',')[0] + "  :  " + attributesstr);
                    count_Children++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so for subgroups, i just have to get attributes["member"] query to return all the users and groups and then i have to retrive the groups corresponding to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this too hard. Assuming you are using Microsoft Active Directory and your desire is to get the Groups that are members of an existing group, I think you can use a filter such as:

```
(&(objectCategory=group)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET))
```

If you want all the members, including users:

```
(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

Or to retrieve only users:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=GroupOne,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)
```

Got most of this from [ldapwiki](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20Group%20Related%20Searches)

Let us know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. :) However, the thing is why i am using LDAPconnection classes is that, it is not sure that it will be connected only to Microsoft Active Directory. I will let you know if it works thanks :)

Comment: The searches ONLY work for Microsoft Active Directory.  http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941